# upgrading glibc to a version at least 2.17 or higher in ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, glibc

I need a newer version of glibc in my ubuntu version (precise, 12.04), but I don't seem to be able to go beyond version 2.15 using apt-get.  I tried to compile it by myself but I almost destroyed my distribution, so I was wondering if someone has gone through this process successfully and would be so kind to guide me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For such an update you will need to update your Ubuntu completely as every package linking to libc will need to be recompiled. And these are a lot.

Comment: I see.  Thank you.   I updated ubuntu and things are working now.